# React/Typescript not recognizing iframe properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript, iframe, declaration

I am trying to embed an iframe that plays a Vimeo with frameborder and allowfullscreen properties on it with a MyOwnComponent like so:

```
const MyOwnVimeoComponent = () => {
return (
    <div>
        <iframe 
            src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/VIMEOID" 
            width="640" 
            height="360" 
            frameborder="0" 
            webkitallowfullscreen 
            mozallowfullscreen 
            allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
    </div>
);}
```

However, the error I get is:

```
[ts] Property 'frameborder' does not exist on type 'HTMLProps<HTMLIFrameElement>'
```

Same for `webkitallowfullscreen`, `mozallowfullscreen` and `allowfullscreen`

After researching other similar problems on StackOverflow it led me to inspect Typescript's lib.d.ts file and look the `<HTMLIFrameElement>` interface and variable declarations.

The interface does in fact have the properties `frameborder` and `allowfullscreen` types on it but it still throws the error.  I would understand if it only threw an error for the `webkitallowfullscreen` and `mozallowfullscreen` but I am generally confused as to what is happening here.

If anyone can point me in the right direction the would be greatly appreciated.

For reference, here is what seems to be the relevant portion of the `lib.d.ts` file:

```
interface HTMLIFrameElement extends HTMLElement, GetSVGDocument {
align: string;
allowFullscreen: boolean;
allowPaymentRequest: boolean;
border: string;
readonly contentDocument: Document;
readonly contentWindow: Window;
frameBorder: string;
frameSpacing: any;
height: string;
hspace: number;
longDesc: string;
marginHeight: string;
marginWidth: string;
name: string;
noResize: boolean;
onload: (this: HTMLIFrameElement, ev: Event) => any;
readonly sandbox: DOMSettableTokenList;
scrolling: string;
src: string;
vspace: number;
width: string;
addEventListener<K extends keyof HTMLIFrameElementEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: HTMLIFrameElement, ev: HTMLIFrameElementEventMap[K]) => any, useCapture?: boolean): void;
addEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, useCapture?: boolean): void;
}

declare var HTMLIFrameElement: {
    prototype: HTMLIFrameElement;
    new(): HTMLIFrameElement;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you can see in the `lib.d.ts` file, it should be `frameBorder`, not `frameborder`.

Don't worry, it took me a while to spot it too!

Comment: It's [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#deprecated_attributes) in 2021: "You should not use [it] in new content, and try to remove [it] from existing content."

Comment: Update: But it looks like my component is still accepting it, and an ugly border does appear when it's not there. (Could probably be removed with CSS.)

Answer (score 6):

See the Following Properties of typed files...

```
    interface IframeHTMLAttributes<T> extends HTMLAttributes<T> {
        allow?: string;
        allowFullScreen?: boolean;
        allowTransparency?: boolean;
        frameBorder?: number | string;
        height?: number | string;
        marginHeight?: number;
        marginWidth?: number;
        name?: string;
        sandbox?: string;
        scrolling?: string;
        seamless?: boolean;
        src?: string;
        srcDoc?: string;
        width?: number | string;
    }
```